# Можно ли как-то предусмотреть в программе на WinAPI корректный выход, когда программа прибивается из диспетчера задач?

Tags: c++, winapi

Лаунчер запускает несколько приложений и остаётся в трее. Нужно чтобы при закрытии лаунчера из диспетчера（или любым другим KillProcess-способом), он тянул за собой все запущенные им приложения (обработка закрытия приложений прописана в case WM_CLOSE лаунчера).

Такое возможно? Если да, то как?

Comment: А как Ваш лаунчер сейчас открывает приложения ?

Comment: Чисто теоретически можно в дочерних процессах смотреть что родитель жив... Но это если дочерние вами писаны

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, нельзя. Кейс для сообщения типа `WN_CLOSE` сработает при закрытии приложения, но никак ни в том случае, когда Вы убиваете процесс. В терминах unix-систем: закрыть приложение - это отправить сигнал `SIGTERM`, а вот убить/завершить процесс - это `SIGKILL`. И его нельзя ни перехватить, ни проигнорировать ( во всяком случае, в контексте  `Unix` ).

Comment: Я не могу припомнить как понять что процесс прибивают. Поэтому согласен что в общем никак.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, вот если бы можно было создать дочерний процесс, который бы осиротел, а, значит, приобрел родителя - _init_, и после этого его бы сделать зомби. :)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, это все бред, конечно, но как я понимаю - такого рода сигналы до самого приложения то и не доходят - они перехватываются ОС. Можно, наверное, только отложить SIGKILL, но из этого тоже ничего хорошего не выйдет.

Comment: Где ж бред-то? :-D Приложение ничего не получает когда его прибивают. Тут я вас полностью поддерживаю. Есть вариант со вторым приложением, которое отслеживает наличие целевого тем или иным способом, но это уже троянские технологии.

Comment: Так а как от _init_ сделать зомби ?

Comment: Какой такой init? Речь про венду, если что :-)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, черт, точно, извините ))

Comment: Хорошо, понял. Тогда такой вопрос: если исполняемый файл дочернего процесса побитово дописать в конец лаунчера, его можно будет запустить так, как если он был бы записан на диск (то есть слить приложения с лаунчером)? Приложения сторонние - браузер, рабочий клиент и т.д...

Comment: @Iceman, первый комментарий к Вашему посту (мой) - сначала я хотел бы услышать на него ответ, думаю, это помогло ы нам разобраться.

Comment: В папке установки есть лаунчер, Браузер\\Имя_браузера.exe и Клиент\\Имя_клиента.exe. Запуск приложений при старте лаунчера: CreateProcess с путём к браузеру и CreateProcess с путём к клиенту

Comment: @Iceman, не знаю, что будет, если Вы сделаете так, хотели - мне кажется, ничего не заработает ) Но буду рад, если Вы меня в этом переубедите. Чтобы слить приложения с лаунчером, попробуйте стд. тулзу IEXPRESS.

Comment: Но Вы же понимаете, что это Вашу проблему никак не решит ?)

Answer (score 0):

В общем, если кому вдруг пригодится, решил задачу так:

Создал ещё одно приложение - бота который следит за лаунчером. Если лаунчер внезапно пропадает из процессов, то бот выполняет предусмотренные в WM_CLOSE лаунчера инструкции. Сам лаунчер тоже следит за ботом - если его пользователь прибил, то лаунчер корректно завершает работу. То есть друг без друга они не работают.